# When the application is executed for the first time application Log Or register

Tags: android, registration, connect

When the application is executed for the first time
application Log
Or register
* When you connect
Connection with the university's database
And brings you information about you
And the material studied by
and your score

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: I want to program an android app, once download and install asks the student to register with their name and password to get his grades examinations.
  help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't understand what exactly you want overall but to check if application ran for the first time, you need to store it in a variable:

```
if (!SettingsPreferences.FirstRun)
    // do something else since not first run
else
    // first run
```

Using something like this:

```
public static bool FirstRun
    {
        get { return Settings.AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(StringConstants.FirstRun, FirstRunDefault); }

        set { Settings.AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(StringConstants.FirstRun, value); }
    }
```